# Fontes personalizadas não carregam no Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Eu estou tentando adicionar fontes personalizadas no meu projeto com expo, mas mesmo seguindo a documentação e o AppLoading retornando que as fontes foram carregadas o texto não muda de fonte ao colocar o `fontFamily`

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Pokeball from './assets/patterns/pokeball.svg' 


import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';


const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
  'sf-pro-display-bold': require('./assets/fonts/sf-pro-display-bold.ttf'),
  'sf-pro-display-medium': require('./assets/fonts/sf-pro-display-medium.ttf'),
  'sf-pro-display-regular': require('./assets/fonts/sf-pro-display-regular.ttf')
  });
};
 
import Home from  './src/pages/home'

export default function App() {

  const [dataLoad, setDataLoad] = useState(false);

  if(!dataLoad){
    return(
      <AppLoading
      startAsync={fetchFonts}
      onFinish={() => {setDataLoad(true)}}
      onError={console.warn}/>
    )
  }else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Pokeball width={'100%'} height={'100%'} fillOpacity={0.05} style={styles.imageBackground}/>
        <Home />
<Text style={styles.teste}>Teste</Text>
      </View>
    
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  imageBackground: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '-48%'
  }, 
  teste: {
    fontFamily: 'sf-pro-display-bold',
  }
});
```